# Wordpress Images cut off on Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I am using WPTouch to create a mobile version of my website http://www.BetterDecoratingbible.com

Everything works great except for the blog post images that are cut off in all the posts. How can I make the images resize for mobile to fit on the page?

Comment: Show us your effort (your code).

Answer (score 0):

Add this css rule to your images on mobile devices.

```
.post img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed it using that code. Do you have any idea how I can center the images on my pages: http://betterdecoratingbible.com/home-tours/ on mobile?

Comment: Remove class 'pull-left' from your img markup, and it will works fine.

Comment: Thank you! I set it to: .pt-cv-thumbnail.pull-left {
 margin-right: auto !important;
} and it works great

Comment: Everything looks great on mobile on this page: betterdecoratingbible.com/home-tours but on another page that uses the same plugin http://betterdecoratingbible.com/diy/ the text is squishing beside the image.How can I make it the same like on the page for "home tours" where the image is centered and the text goes below the image? Does anyone know? Thank you.

Comment: This image needs to have `width: 100%` in CSS, additionally I think that you can remove class `pull-left` from image.

Comment: Thank you thats amazing your so good at this! Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a class on your page overriding this class:

```
.post img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

The class you're looking for is:

```
p img {
max-width: 600px !important;
height: auto;
}
```

Either change the `max-width: 600px !important;` to `max-width: 100% !important;` or remove '!important' so that the other class can take preference.

Comment: Thank you!! Solved my problem just changed it to max-width: 100%;